# What is the range $f(x,y)= (x+y, \frac{1}{y-1},x^2+y^2)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions

How should one proceed to find the range, doing $z=x+y+ \frac{1}{y-1}+x^2+y^2$ or by making $t=x$ and substitution, what visual inspection gives me the right clue here?

Comment: This function is $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^3$. The range should be a region in three dimensional space.

Comment: This is a parametric surface. Try setting $(x,y,z)=f(u,v)$ and establishing a relation between $x,y,$ and $z$ via eliminating the variables $u$ and $v$. You will be able to express this surface in the form $z=g(x,y)$ for some function $g$.

Comment: Thanks I'm following now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint}$: We have that

$$\begin{cases}y = \frac{1+v}{v}\\ x = u - \frac{1+v}{v}\end{cases}$$

$$\implies w = u^2 -2xy = u^2 +\frac{2(1+v)}{v}\left(\frac{1+v}{v}-u\right)$$